# CRUD using Java and XML Database

Tags: java, xml, crud

I am looking to add, edit, remove and delete entries in an XML database using java. The code below has all the getters and setters for the entries in my XML database. How do I get values from my XML into the appropriate objects?

```
public class contact implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column
private int Id;
@Column
private String firstname;
@Column
private String lastname;
@Column
private String email;

public int getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(int Id) {
    this.Id = Id;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public contact(int Id, String firstname, String lastname, String email) {
    this.Id = Id;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.email = email;
}
```

Comment: is there a logical difference between remove and delete? oh please obey this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: "*how do i get values from my xml into the appropriate objects.*" hmmm wave your wand or simply write the code that does this... have you tried that? yes? please show! no? do it now!